# Practical FlapJax

Tags: javascript

Has anybody used or seen a website that uses [FlapJax](http://www.flapjax-lang.org/) to function, rather than just as a demo? I'm curious to see how they operate / how difficult they were to write.

List one example per answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the one app per answer request:

http://continue2.cs.brown.edu/

http://resumedemo.cs.brown.edu/

Keep in mind though that these were made by the developers of Flapjax.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using it for a page internal to my employer that is largely a very fancy clock. Just using the library directly (skipping the compiler, which they plan to deprecate) has worked great. Event streams are very convenient when you've got a whole lot of different components, coming and going, that have to be synchronized.
So, sorry, can't show you anything, but I've been very pleased with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just can across this question and thought people might be interested in the website we're developing. It's currently still in beta stage, but it depends heavily on the FlapJax javascript library. Website [here](https://my.ihome.eu). Bear in mind that not all code is FlapJax and that there ALOT of javascript on there so it might take some scrounging to find the good bits.

Extra info about the site and it's purpose can be found [here](http://www.ihome.eu/).

Comment: is it possible to see anything without logging in?

Comment: Sadly we changed our site quite a bit since I posted this comment. So it won't be really possible to view the code any more (you have to buy products in order to gain access).

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used Flapjax in various websites and web applications. At work i am currently creating an interface for a managed switch that is entirely flapjax based.

The key things you should consider are:

- Flapjax is an FRP library, (Functional Reactive Programming)
- FRP works best at scale.
- Its all about management of both state and events.
- It only works when the whole system is FRP

The little examples don't do the system justice.

My NodeJS based Flapjax frp framework is on GitHub, although its not quite ready yet. http://github.com/Zysen/Aurora

This is my description of FRP which you may find helpful
https://github.com/Zysen/Aurora/wiki